# Mysterious Echo Rules in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch program that is supposed to be like a simplified(-ish) command prompt for commands that I make. I am wondering, though, about this line of batch coding that I have narrowed down as a fatal error (causes the cmd.exe running the program to close) causing line: `echo One(1) application is within this folder`. When I attempt to go to that section via inputting the command to run that section it states: `application was unexpected at this time` followed by immediately closing. I have also tried replacing "application" with "program", to no avail. I was wondering: What are all of the mysterious echo parameters/rules. for instance `echo text >> name.extention` is possible, but typing `echo /?` does not give you anything besides `@echo on/off` and `echo text`.

I believe it is something to do with the (), as in other languages it is used to call a function with the arguments within the (), but I do not understand why it would be this, as it is not running the "One" function because it is inside an echo, meant only to display it literally. Also, I don't believe batch has functions that can be called like this (I've only seen them in VB, lua, java, and C++ [of the ones I use])

If anyone knows why the program failed at this line, and/or (preferably and) all of the other hidden echo rules, please list them out for us; they really need to be known (I've seen so many questions on this website [and others] specifically about the echo command).

Comment: please try to buy a _Windows Command Shell Language textbook_, here is **not** the tutorial channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a block statement where you have `if expression (whatever1) else (whetever2)` then you need to escape a closing parentheseis `)` with a caret `^` thusly : `^)`

The escape tells batch that the `)` is NOT the termination of the then/else

Comment: OK, that actually makes a lot of sense; I originally thought it couldn't be that because there was an open to pair to it, but it must have taken the second open as literal since there was no if statement with it, thanks.